# How can I print the same list twice without empty it?

Tags: python, list, python-itertools

I am practising using the `itertool.accumulate` function with some loops and ifs. As results, I would like a list of the single numbers (variable is called "calls") and the sum of every cycle, which are 3.

Now, I have manage to get both lists, but not at the same time. What I mean is that it looks like once a list is printed, it becomes empty. am I missing something? How can I have both lists printed?

I'm going to post both codes with outputs to show you what I mean.

**FIRST CODE: it prints only the single values**

```
import random as rnd
import itertools

# variables
a = 5
b = int(1)
########
calls = (
    tuple((itertools.accumulate(
        a if a > rnd.randint(1, 10) else -a
        for i in range(b)
        for j in range(2))
    )
    )
    for cycle in range(3)
)
#######
print(list(calls))
print(list(sum(call) for call in calls))
```

> [(5, 0), (-5, -10), (5, 0)]
>
> []

**SECOND CODE: it prints only the sum of values**
    import random as rnd
    import itertools

```
# variables
a = 5
b = int(1)
########
calls = (
    tuple((itertools.accumulate(
        a if a > rnd.randint(1, 10) else -a
        for i in range(b)
        for j in range(2))
    )
    )
    for cycle in range(3)
)
#######
print(list(sum(call) for call in calls)
print(list(calls))
```

> [5, -15, 5]
>
> []

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest solution: Convert it to a `list` directly:

```
calls = list(    # only changed here
    tuple((itertools.accumulate(
        a if a > rnd.randint(1, 10) else -a
        for i in range(b)
        for j in range(2))
    )
    )
    for cycle in range(3)
)
```

The problem is that you create a [generator expression (PEP 289)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) when you use:

```
(... for cycle in range(3))
```

and generator expressions cannot be reused, they are for lazy-one-time evaluation.

You could instead also use a list comprehension `[ ... ]` instead of `( ... )`:

```
calls = [
    tuple((itertools.accumulate(
        a if a > rnd.randint(1, 10) else -a
        for i in range(b)
        for j in range(2))
    )
    )
    for cycle in range(3)
]
```